# Redirect back to original visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, lookup

I have created a custom page for an object client. The client object is having relationship with contact object. For this a custom lookup window has been designed with a new button for creating new record of contact. Now after clicking the save button I want it to redirect me on the client page with the value saved as populated in the contact relationship field.

Below is my code:

## Client.page

```
<apex:page standardController="Client__c" id="Page" extensions="MyCustomLookupController3"> 
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
  function openLookup(baseURL, width, modified, searchParam){
    var originalbaseURL = baseURL;
    var originalwidth = width;
    var originalmodified = modified;
    var originalsearchParam = searchParam;

    var lookupType = baseURL.substr(baseURL.length-3, 3);
    if (modified == '1') baseURL = baseURL + searchParam;

    var isCustomLookup = false;

    // Following "001" is the lookup type for Account object so change this as per your standard or custom object
    if(lookupType == "003"){

      var urlArr = baseURL.split("&");
      var txtId = '';
      if(urlArr.length > 2) {
        urlArr = urlArr[1].split('=');
        txtId = urlArr[1];
      } 
      // Following is the url of Custom Lookup page. You need to change that accordingly
      baseURL = "/apex/test2?txt=" + txtId; 
      // Following is the id of apex:form control "myForm". You need to change that accordingly
      baseURL = baseURL + "&frm=" + escapeUTF("{!$Component.myForm}");
      if (modified == '1') {
        baseURL = baseURL + "&lksearch=" + searchParam;
      }

      // Following is the ID of inputField that is the lookup to be customized as custom lookup
      if(txtId.indexOf('contact') > -1 ){
        isCustomLookup = true;
      }
    } 
    if(isCustomLookup == true){
      openPopup(baseURL, "lookup", 350, 480, "width="+width+",height=480,toolbar=no,status=no,directories=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,scrollable=no", true);
    }
    else {
      if (modified == '1') originalbaseURL = originalbaseURL + originalsearchParam;
      openPopup(originalbaseURL, "lookup", 350, 480, "width="+originalwidth+",height=480,toolbar=no,status=no,directories=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,scrollable=no", true);
    } 
  }
</script> 
<apex:sectionHeader title="Demo"  subtitle="Custom Lookup" /> 
  <apex:form id="myForm">  
    <apex:PageBlock id="PageBlock">    
      <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" title="Custom Lookup">       
        <apex:inputField id="contact" value="{!Client__c.Contact__c}" />  
        <apex:inputField value="{!Client__c.name}"/>      
      </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:PageBlock>
  </apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

## MyCustomLookupController3.apxc

```
public with sharing class MyCustomLookupController3 {

public Id accId;

public string name;   

public client__c  sap {get;set;}

 public contact contact {get;set;} // new account to create

  public List<contact> results{get;set;} // search results

  public string searchString{get;set;} // search keyword  

  public MyCustomLookupController3() {

    contact = new Contact();

    //account = new Account();

    // get the current search string

    searchString = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('lksrch');

    runSearch();  
  }

  // performs the keyword search

  public PageReference search() {

    runSearch();

    return null;
  } 

  // prepare the query and issue the search command

  private void runSearch() {

    // TODO prepare query string for complex serarches & prevent injections

    results = performSearch(searchString);               
  } 

  private List<contact> performSearch(string searchString) { 

    String soql = 'select id, name from contact';

    if(searchString != '' && searchString != null)

      soql = soql +  ' where name LIKE \'%' + searchString +'%\'';

    soql = soql + ' limit 25';

    System.debug(soql);

    return database.query(soql);  
  }

 public PageReference savecontact() {

    insert contact;

    // reset the account

    Id redirectId = contact.Id;   

    PageReference newocp = new PageReference('/apex/test1?accId='+redirectId);/*Redirect to Parent page*/  

            newocp.setRedirect(true);

            return newocp;            
  } 

  // used by the visualforce page to send the link to the right dom element

  public string getFormTag() {

    return System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('frm');

  } 

// used by the visualforce page to send the link to the right dom element for the text box

  public string getTextBox() {

    return System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('txt');

  }

  public MyCustomLookupController3(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    contact = new contact();

        this.sap = (client__c) controller.getRecord();

        if (ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('accId') != NULL)
 {
            accId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('accId');

            name = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('name');
        }

       if ( accId != null ) {

        this.sap.contact__c = (Id)accId;

        this.sap.name = name;
    }

       /* if (accId != NULL) {

            account = [SELECT ID, name from Account where id = : accId];
        }*/
    }     
}
```

## ClientSearch.page

```
<apex:page controller="MyCustomLookupController3"  title="Search" showHeader="false" sideBar="false" tabStyle="Account" 
  id="pg"> 
  <apex:form >
  <apex:outputPanel id="page" layout="block" style="margin:5px;padding:10px;padding-top:2px;">
    <apex:tabPanel switchType="client" selectedTab="name1" id="tabbedPanel"> 
      <!-- SEARCH TAB -->
      <apex:tab label="Search" name="tab1" id="tabOne"> 
        <apex:actionRegion >  
          <apex:outputPanel id="top" layout="block" style="margin:5px;padding:10px;padding-top:2px;">
            <apex:outputLabel value="Search" style="font-weight:Bold;padding-right:10px;" for="txtSearch"/>
            <apex:inputText id="txtSearch" value="{!searchString}" />
              <span style="padding-left:5px"><apex:commandButton id="btnGo" value="Go" action="{!Search}" rerender="searchResults"></apex:commandButton></span>
          </apex:outputPanel> 
          <apex:outputPanel id="pnlSearchResults" style="margin:10px;height:350px;overflow-Y:auto;" layout="block">
            <apex:pageBlock id="searchResults"> 
              <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!results}" var="a" id="tblResults">
                <apex:column >
                  <apex:facet name="header">
                    <apex:outputPanel >Name</apex:outputPanel>
                  </apex:facet>
                   <apex:outputLink value="javascript:top.window.opener.lookupPick2('{!FormTag}','{!TextBox}_lkid','{!TextBox}','{!a.Id}','{!a.Name}', false)" rendered="{!NOT(ISNULL(a.Id))}">{!a.Name}</apex:outputLink>     
                </apex:column>
              </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageBlock>
          </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:actionRegion> 
      </apex:tab>

      <!-- NEW ACCOUNT TAB -->
      <apex:tab label="New Account" name="tab2" id="tabTwo">

        <apex:pageBlock id="newAccount" title="New Account" >

          <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton action="{!savecontact}" value="Save"/>
          </apex:pageBlockButtons>
          <apex:pageMessages />

          <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
            <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.contact.FieldSets.CustomContactLookup}" var="f">
              <apex:inputField value="{!contact[f]}"/>
            </apex:repeat>
          </apex:pageBlockSection> 
        </apex:pageBlock>

      </apex:tab>
    </apex:tabPanel>
  </apex:outputPanel>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: This needs a lot of formatting cleanup.  Can you please do that?

Answer (score 0):

I got your question. In child page "ClientSearch", you have a command button "savecontact" to save contact record. Add "oncomplete" JavaScript event on this command button. In JavaScript method call parent page JavaScript method and pass newly add contact Id to the parent page.Like:  parent.refreshContact(contactId)

Let me know if you face any difficulty to implement this in your code.